# ld:framework not found sfml

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, sfml

I copied the contents of Frameworks from SFML to ~/Library/Frameworks and tried to run the first tutorial example in SFML.
I used this in g++ :

```
g++ -o sfml-test.cpp -framework SFML -lsfml-window
```

and get this error:

```
ld: framework not found SFML
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the tutorial specifies `/Library/Frameworks`, *not* `~/Library/Frameworks`. `~` points to the user home directory (`/Users/name/`), whereas `/` points to the lowest point on the filesystem.

Also [despite the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002257-BAJJBBHJ), `/Library/Frameworks` is not a standard framework directory, so you have to set it in the search paths. You can see the standard framework directories by running `gcc -Xlinker -v`:

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-409.12
BUILD 17:47:51 Sep 25 2018
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em arm64e arm64_32
Library search paths:
    /usr/local/lib
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note the `Framework search paths` section, it does not include `/Library/Frameworks`.

To add `/Library/Frameworks` to the search path, compile with `-F/Library/Frameworks` and link with `-F/Library/Frameworks -framework SFML -framework sfml-x`, x being `system`, `window`, `graphics`, `audio` or `network`.

Also, the `-o` option specifies the output filename. Your command would take no input files and output the executable `sfml-test.cpp`, so use `-o sfml-test sfml-test.cpp` to take `sfml-test.cpp` as input, and output `sfml-test`.

Your command would be:

`g++ -o sfml-test sfml-test.cpp -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SFML -framework sfml-window`

Comment: I tried that, but I get following error:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)